# Enemy Follow Player Orthogonal Movement

Tags: c#, xna

I have a Enemy class that Seeks a player if he is in his field of view.
Problem is i want the enemy only to move up/down/right/left, not like for example up and left at the same time (diagonal movement).

**EDIT: Updated code and image**

```
    private void SeekPlayer(Player player)
    {
        //directionToPlayer is a 2DVector
        //Image is a class i made that takes a texture, position (Vector2D), etc..
        directionToPlayer = player.Image.Position - Image.Position;
        directionToPlayer.Normalize();

        bool Horizontal = true;//Bool that indicates the direction 


        if (Math.Abs(directionToPlayer.Y) - Math.Abs(directionToPlayer.X) > 1f)//your distance to change direction
        {
            Horizontal = false;//if y is bigger, don't move horizontal
        }

        if (Math.Abs(directionToPlayer.X) - Math.Abs(directionToPlayer.Y) > 1f)//your distance to change direction 
        {
            Horizontal = true;
        }

        if(Horizontal)
            directionToPlayer.Y = 0;
        else
            directionToPlayer.X = 0;

    Velocity = directionToPlayer;
    Image.Position += Velocity;
    UpdateFOV();
}
```

With the current code the enemy sometimes follows the play on the X coordinates, and when it's the same has the player's, doesn't continue to follow on the Y coordinate. And vice-versa for Y.

[image: Gameplay]

Comment: because it moves a bit at X and then moves a bit at Y... and in general it looks he is moving diagonal? if so... then you must calculate `X` and `Y` differences between `Enemy` and `Player`. say Enemy is moving at X coordinate. so he must continue moving at X till `Enemy.X - Player.X` gets close to 0. then start moving at Y axis.

Comment: Hm to continue move at `X`, i just have to set the `difference.Y` to 0, right ? And when `difference.X` is equal to 0, he moves at `Y`. I did that, but the enemy only moves at `X` untill the right position but never moves at `Y` afterwards.

Comment: i dont know how your enemy starts moving. but i think you should add another condition that if `difference.X` equals to 0 then start moving at `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace your if statements with this.

```
Bool Horizontal = true;//Bool that indicates the direction 


if (Math. Abs(directionToPlayer.Y) - Math.Abs(directionToPlayer.X)> 1)//your distance to change direction
{
    Horizontal = false;//if y is bigger, don't move horizontal
}

if (Math. Abs(directionToPlayer.X) - Math.Abs(directionToPlayer.Y)> 1)//your distance to change direction 
{
    Horizontal = true;
} 

If(Horizontal) 
    directionToPlayer.Y = 0;
Else
    directionToPlayer.X =0;
```

Sorry for the layout, I'm on mobile.

Comment: Hm i updated with your code but the enemy never follows the player on Y axis.. I think it has to do with the float precision ?

Comment: I don't know at what distance you need to change direction. I assumed 1,but I think it is not correct. Try 30 or so